# How to call disclaimer page on all media files in Drupal?

Tags: media, hooks

I want to display a **terms n condition** page on every **media** of website. I collect all media from `file managed` table of database. I also convert `fid` to `url`. Now for each **media url** I need a **disclaimer page**.

My issue is something related to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709195/drupal-7-download-pdf-after-form-submit).

**For example:**

When I click on *each report of news table* shown below, on clicking of (say) `linux-minimal.pdf` , it first redirect to **some node which is my disclaimer url**, and then **pdf open**.

**How can I achieve this?**

I have tried some code which is actually not working. It is:

```
function hook_init(){
    $get_current_path_media = $GLOBALS['base_url'].'/'.current_path();
    if($get_current_path_media == 'http://my-website/sites/default/files/569338.pdf'){
        drupal_goto('disclaimer');
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If I were you, I would use jQuery, instead of php, to display a popup disclaimer and after the user closes or accepts the disclaimer, they are then taken to the pdf file.

Comment: any drupal way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
<a class="test" href="https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf">bitcoin.pdf</a>

<script>
    $('.test').click(function() {
    alert('Your disclamer goes here');
});
</script>
```

[SEE A DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/e5pfdr12/20/)

**In Drupal to use jQuery you need to wrap it in**

```
(function ($) {

    //code goes here

})(jQuery);
```

so your code should look like this

```
(function ($) {
  $( document ).ready(function() { 
    $('.test').click(function() {
        alert('your disclamer goes here');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

PS: If your div class is outside the `<a>`

```
<div class="test"><a href="https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf">bitcoin.pdf</a></div>
```

then use it like this

```
<script>
(function ($) {
  $( document ).ready(function() { 
    $('.test a').click(function() {
        alert('your disclamer goes here');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: edited my answer, fixed errors.